# How to hide system tray menu items in odoo 12

Tags: xml, odoo, odoo-12

There is a header menu in Odoo home view, I'd like to hide to show it only to a certain group in odoo, so far I located the buttons to be in this path odoo/addons/mail/static/src/xml/systray.xml

How can I edit those menu items using a custom module?

I just don't want [to modify directly](https://www.odoo.com/fr_FR/forum/aide-1/question/how-can-i-hide-system-tray-icons-in-menu-bar-by-the-side-of-user-name-115512) the systray.xml I understand that's more like a static asset.

In my case, I'd like to hide the clock, conversation dropdown, and some menu items in the user options, check the image for further details:

[image]

```
<i aria-label="Activities" class="fa fa-clock-o" role="img"></i>
<i aria-label="Messages" class="fa fa-comments" role="img"></i>
```

Answer (score 2):

The systray menu items `(message, activity)` are actually JavaScript widgets, written in `odoo/addons/mail/static/src/js/systray/systray_activity_menu.js` and `odoo/addons/mail/static/src/js/systray/systray_messaging_menu.js` files. The widgets are added to the view using `SystrayMenu.Items.push` function. You can disable this widgets by removing those `.js` files from `mail.assets_backend` view.

```
<template id="assets_backend" inherit_id="mail.assets_backend">    
    <xpath expr="//script[@src='/mail/static/src/js/systray/systray_activity_menu.js']" position="replace" />
    <xpath expr="//script[@src='/mail/static/src/js/systray/systray_messaging_menu.js']" position="replace" />
</template>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sorry brother, Yours didnt work on my Odoo 12.. so i made more changes and below one is working

```
<t t-extend="mail.systray.MessagingMenu">
    <t t-jquery=".o_mail_systray_item" t-operation="replace">
       <t ></t>
    </t>
</t>
<t t-extend="mail.systray.ActivityMenu">
    <t t-jquery=".o_mail_systray_item" t-operation="replace">
        <t ></t>
    </t>
</t>
```

Answer (score 1):

After some research done, I found a solution that might meet your need.

For Odoo 15, do the following to remove items from the user menu.

```
    /** @odoo-module **/
    import { UserMenu } from "@web/webclient/user_menu/user_menu";
    import { patch } from "@web/core/utils/patch";
    import { registry } from "@web/core/registry";

    const userMenuRegistry = registry.category("user_menuitems");

    //For remove menu:
    patch(UserMenu.prototype, "base_user_cuid.UserMenu", {
        setup() {
            this._super.apply(this, arguments);

            userMenuRegistry.remove("documentation");
            userMenuRegistry.remove("support");
            userMenuRegistry.remove("shortcuts");
            userMenuRegistry.remove("odoo_account");
        },
    });
```

Then in the manifest file:

```
    'assets': {'web.assets_backend': ['Your custom module name/static/src/js/menu.js']},
```

Please check this file for more:
/web/static/src/webclient/user_menu/user_menu_items.js

Thanks for the reading !

Comment: This answer is great in terms of details and explanation!  But it doesn't explain how to remove activities and conversations.